# How to use ipywidgets in jupyter-notebook without Internet

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, voila

I have developed interactive application in python using jupyter notebook with ipywidgets and use voila to run the notebook.
On my development system (with internet) I have the application working flawlessly. But on the system without internet the application does not load. On inspection with developer tools, the web application is trying to load scripts from [mathjax](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/latest.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML-full,Safe), [font-awesome](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@%5E5/css/all.min.css)  and [here](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@%5E5/css/v4-shims.min.css)

If anyone could guide me on how to workaround this problem ? Run jupyter notebook application with ipywidgets without internet. Can we change some settings / configuration to use the static copy of these dependencies?

---- Update
On the system without internet, running jupyter lab and notebook and running the cells works perfectly fine. I am able to view the font-awesome icons and other ipywidgets. This issue is observed only using voila

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: One suggestion would be to summarize this and link to this post on the [Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/) in the hopes of getting more eyes to see this. There's been talk, more about in the JupyterLite context, about making things work better offline ultimately and so maybe someone knows a better path than any clunky workaround I could suggest looking into.

Comment: Thank you @Wayne I have added a [post](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/running-voila-without-internet/13823) at the Jupyter Discourse Forum.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like we need to override the references to cdn and fontawesome in the templates of voila with local references.
Please find the reply from Jupyter discourse forum [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/running-voila-without-internet/13823/2).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue about "font-awesome" icons which is not working with voila. To workaround it, I'm now using unicode characters in description strings instead of icon property.

Answer (score 0):

voila still requires some scripts from internet as of March 2023.

I tried to fix it by customizing templates but I was not able to do it for MathJax. I worked it around by replacing internet URLs with local ones with nginx and I am sharing my config as it could be useful to someone else.

```
  sub_filter_types text/html text/css application/javascript;
  sub_filter 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/latest.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML-full,Safe' '/vendor/mathjax-2.7.7-TeX-MML-AM_CHTML-full.Safe.js';
  sub_filter 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/latest.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML-full,Safe' '/vendor/mathjax-2.7.7-TeX-AMS_CHTML-full,Safe.js';
  sub_filter '[MathJax]/extensions/MathMenu.js' '/vendor/MathMenu-2.7.7.js';
  sub_filter '[MathJax]/extensions/MathZoom.js' '/vendor/MathZoom-2.7.7.js';
  sub_filter 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@^5/css/all.min.css' '/vendor/fontawesome.min.css';
  sub_filter 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@^5/css/v4-shims.min.css' '/vendor/fontawesome-v4-shims.min.css';
  sub_filter_once on;
```